# Json Flatten using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data in a below json format:

```
id,hardware_json
1,{hardware[0]_id:123,hardware[0]_name:ModelA,hardware[0]_type:M,hardware[1]_id:345,hardware[1]_name:ModelB,hardware[0]_type:N,hardware[0]_vendor:cnfd....}
```

now for each hardware id we can n number of attributes and for some hardware only some attributes present. I need to make in below format using python?

```
Id,hardware_id,hardware_name,hardware_type,hardware_vendor
1,123,ModelA,M
1,345,ModelB,N,cnfd
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks

I am looking for any json embedded function in the python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't recognize that json format.  Looks like a CSV format.

Comment: That is not JSON. Can you tell us more about what is generating that data?

Comment: hardware_json column is in the array/json format .. I want to unpivot it in the format I mentioned.